# How to make Tab bar for Android like TabBarIOS in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to create a BottomTabBar for my app. 
I have used TabBarIOS component for the same and it works perfectly on iOS. Is there any component for the Android as well?

I have checked react-native-tabs but it doesn't support images I guess and the badge icon for notification.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

I guess this plugin will serve your purpose:

https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-scrollable-tab-view